# Galaxy S8 has no option to show CPU usage

Tags: cpu, overlay

My Samsung Galaxy S8 (SM-G950F) is not showing the developer option to "Show CPU usage".
I have turned the "Developer options" on, but scrolling down to "Monitoring" I only get 2 options: "Strict mode enabled" and "Profile GPU rendering".
I don't know why is it not available and how can I get it.
I keep getting a message "Abnormal account. You need to login again." about every 15 minutes on my screen, but I have no idea which app is doing this, so I'm trying to track it.

Comment: AFAIK, there has never been "show CPU usage" on the developer option. Have you seen this menu on other devices/some guides? Note though that manufacturers can customize their Android OS, including the developer options.

Comment: If the action occurs as often as every 15m then the Battery Usage could probably show some consumption. Look under `Device Care > Battery > Usage By Apps` for a clue.